# Is there a way to cloud transfer Borderlands 2 Saves?

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands-2, xbox-one, xbox-network

I am most commonly living in one of two places.

- Place A has an Xbox one with the Borderlands Handsome Collection.
- Place B has an Xbox 360 with Borderlands 2.

I know that using the built in save-transfer tool, Place B's save can go to place A, but is there a built in way, does Microsoft's cloud save service have the ability, or is there something I an do to transfer the saves from Place A to place B? it is *very* annoying having an item on one, but not on the other version, and playing missions multiple times over.

Tools at my disposal:
\Xbox One (+BLands2 DLC, because handsome collection)\  \Windows PC\  \Xbox 360 (No DLC)\  \External USB HDD\  \External USB Flash Storage Device\

Comment: Interesting. It removed my friendly `Hello.` at the top. Is that a quality-assurance feature?

Comment: Not so much a QA feature, but more of a "getting to the point" feature. We at Stack Exchange don't really care about cordiality and niceties beyond "don't be a horrible human being". We'd rather you get to the point with your question. There's no reason to post hello, because these are meant to be reference questions. There is no reason to post thank you comments, that's what upvoting answers is for (unless you had to change minor things about your implementation of the answer because your situation is different than assumed).

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in way to move your XBOX 360 saves to the XBOX One, namely via the "Cloud Save" function, for more detailed information on how to do that read [this](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/2015/03/cross-save-in-borderlands-the-handsome-collection-updated/) article on the official GearBox (developers of BL) site.

However, you can't move saves from the XBOX One to the XBOX 360 as Microsoft doesn't support that. The proof for that is in the article I already quoted. Notice that it says

> Please note:
>       The Xbox family of systems can only move saves from Xbox 360 to Xbox One and not the other way around.

around halfway through the article.